# Best way to prevent "mux_client_request_session: read from master failed: Broken pipe" ssh errors

Tags: perl, ssh-tunnel

I've got a perl script that creates an ssh tunnel and sets up a Perl DBI connection across it to query a database on a remote host:

```
1 my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new('me@host.com');
2 $pid = $ssh->spawn({ssh_opts => '-L 127.0.0.1:12345:127.0.0.1:3306'}, 'sleep 3');

3 return DBI->connect($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);
```

This works about 80 to 90% of the time but the rest of the time I get this error when trying to connect to the database:

> mux_client_request_session: read from master failed: Broken pipe

In the process of troubleshooting this, I noticed if I sleep the program very briefly after line 2 with `usleep (10000)`, it works 100% of the time. I'm not sure why this is but I'm curious know and how I can properly fix the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a race condition in your code: `spawn` runs the `ssh` command that starts the tunnel on the background, sometimes that command is faster than DBI `connect` starting the TCP socket, sometimes it isn't and so `connect` fails.

Anyway, the way I usually recommend to create tunnels is to use a control command:

```
 $ssh->system({ssh_opts => [-O => 'forward', '-L3066:localhost:3066']})
```

If you want to remove the tunnel once the connection to the database has been established:

```
 $ssh->system({ssh_opts => [-O => 'cancel', '-L3066:localhost:3066']});
```

Also, note that you have to keep the `Net::OpenSSH` object alive as long as you want to use the DB connection.

In summary:

```
sub dbi_connect {
    my $mysql_port = 3066;
    my $local_port = 12345;
    my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=localhost;port=$local_port";
    my $tunnel = join ':', $local_port, 'localhost', $mysql_port;
    my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, ...);
    $ssh->system({ssh_opts => [-O => 'forward', "-L$tunnel"]});
    my $dbi = DBI->connect($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);
    $ssh->system({ssh_opts => [-O => 'cancel', "-L$tunnel"]});
    return ($dbi, $ssh);
}
```

See also [this post](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1189875) at PerlMonks.

Comment: Thank you. What goes in the $dsn? Also, since I'm not on Windows, I assume I use 3306 for the mysql port instead of 4022?

Comment: `$dsn` should point to the local side of the tunnel. I have included an example above for mysql.

Comment: Thanks. I will test this out as soon as I get a chance.